# Mouse programming

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, mousemove

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466359/graphics-editor-in-c

I've developed a simple graphics editor in c++.It requires me to drag the mouse to draw a shape .After drawing the shape I want to fill it by picking a color but since dragging the mouse amounts to a large number of clicks because of which the entire screen gets filled with a default color even before i've drawn the shape. delay() doesn't work either.

Comment: what are u using opengl?

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are asking without some code or a picture. You know how to attach an image to your question, right?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint but i'm using Turbo C++.

Comment: Presumably you can let the user pick a color after they let go of the mouse button and stop drawing the shape.

Comment: The link above was an earlier attempt.I'll put up the new one.

Comment: @RaymondChen :That is exactly what i want to do but before i can pick a color the steps ahead in the code are executed.

Comment: Um, you wrote the steps ahead. Write your code so the color-picker runs first.

Comment: Okay,that's a good tip I'd try that.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the mouse click event in turbo c++ has two part. one where you press the button and two when you release the button. you need to drag so you should use the clrscr() function in the loop which goes on iterating until the mouse button is pressed down along with the code for the shape you want to draw. that way your screen keeps getting updated when you are dragging the mouse. and the loop ends when you release the button.
for filling the shape using the flood fill function should suffice

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of the following links is what you're looking for:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11313/Mouse-Programming-in-C-C
- http://www.cprogrammingreference.com/Tutorials/Advance_Tutorials/mouseprogramming.php
- http://www.brackeen.com/vga/mouse.html

Comment: Thanks a lot but i've already visited these links.I'm okay with the basics but my problem is i cant keep track of the current mouse position or rather its not in my control.The link at the top is the code i've written.Could you please just help me with the pick_color() function.